# What does the Mann Co. Painting Set do?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What does the Mann Co. Painting set do? Is it like normal paint? Does it allow paint to be changed on hats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mann Co. Painting Set is like a Mann Co. Mystery Box.

It can be 'unboxed' and will give you 3 random paint colors when you unbox it.

It is exactly like normal paint. There is no difference between "paints from painting set" and "normal paint".

If you wish to see a demonstration, [here is a link.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjDFLgxnaMU)

A discussion can be found [here.](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=34139883)